# Monaca for Visual Studioでmonacaのプロジェクトをクライアントに保存出来ない

Tags: monaca, visual-studio, vb.net

Monaca for Visual Studioでmonacaのプロジェクトをクライアントに保存しようとすると「インターフェースがサポートされていません」のエラーメッセージが出るのですがクライアントへの保存は出来ないのでしょうか？
同じ質問を過去にされた方がいますが、回答も付かないし、スタッフのサポートも無いので、
途方に暮れています。
まだトライアル期間中ですが、プランはゴールドです。
VSでコードを弄った後に保存する手段が全く無いのです。
ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ここはMonacaに限らずプログラミングの情報交換を行うサイトなので、Monacaのサポートチームが対応してくれるわけではありません。極端な話、Monaca側のバグだとしたらここでは解決できない可能性もあるため、Monaca公式の問い合わせ窓口(https://ja.monaca.io/service/)を利用することもご検討ください。

Comment: それはそれとして、もう少し情報を追加していただくことはできませんか？VisualStudio上で新規作成したプロジェクトなのかクラウドIDEからインポートしたものなのか、エラーがいつどのように出るのか（手順やエラー時のスクリーンショット）、VisualStudioやMonaca for Visual Studioのバージョン等々。